# Extract a part of an id

Tags: javascript, jquery

I've got multiple divs with ids. I need to remove a certain part of a div ID and get it onto a variable. How can I do this? example:

```
<div id="fruitapple14754"></div>
<div id="fruitapple1564"></div>
<div id="fruitapple14"></div>
```

I need to remove `fruitapple1` from the id and get the remaining part assigned to a variable. The length of `fruitapple1` is always the same.

Comment: @Script47 yep.... that's good. Can you show how.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `substr` for this here is how to use:-

```
var ids=[];
$('[id^="fruitapple"]').each(function(){
 var id=$(this).attr('id');
  ids.push(id.substr(11));
 });

alert(JSON.stringify(ids));
```

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/c6gc9rmn/)

Comment: I find your solution more suited to me. thank you :)

Comment: @Bekki glad if this helps you :)

Answer (score 2):

You can get an array of all the IDs like this:

```
var collection = [];

$('[id^="fruitapple"]').each(getId);

function getId() {
  var id = $(this).attr('id').split('fruitapple1').pop();

  collection.push(id);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The simplest way would be to replace it with an empty string

```js
$('[id^="fruitapple"]').each(function() {
  var subId = $(this).attr('id').replace('fruitapple1', '');
  console.log(subId);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="fruitapple14754"></div>
<div id="fruitapple1564"></div>
<div id="fruitapple14"></div>
```

Comment: thanks :) #up-vote. I find substring() a bit more easier.

Comment: @Bekki, I personally find substring() more involved/complicated because you have to know the exact index you want to start at. Anyways, hope my answer helped :)

Answer (score 1):

Try to use [startwith selector](http://api.jquery.com/attribute-starts-with-selector/),

```
$('[id^="fruitapple1"]').each(function() {
     console.log(this.id.replace('fruitapple1', ''));
});
```

If you want to get it into an array variable then use [map()](http://api.jquery.com/map/) like

```
console.log($('[id^="fruitapple1"]').map(function() {
     return (this.id.replace('fruitapple1', ''));
}).get());
```

```js
console.log($('[id^="fruitapple1"]').map(function() {
     return (this.id.replace('fruitapple1', ''));
}).get());
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="fruitapple14754"></div>
<div id="fruitapple1564"></div>
<div id="fruitapple14"></div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `.substring()` method of javascript.

Check out this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/shrinivas93/gcaqjwq3/).

Here is the snippet.

```js
var divs = document.getElementsByTagName('div');

for (i = 0; i < divs.length; i++) {
  var id = divs[i].id;
  alert(id.substring(11));       // length of 'fruitapple1' = 11
}
```

```html
<div id="fruitapple14754"></div>
<div id="fruitapple1564"></div>
<div id="fruitapple14"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

A simple answer using substring as suggested in my comment. I'm on mobile that's why it took long.

```
var idSubstring = document.getElementById("yourIdHere").id.substring(11);

alert(idSubstring);
```

[Demo JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/ug8oazey/2/)